# Why the appendRow always write twice to G-sheet in Google script?

Tags: javascript, json

I use the Web Apps URL below to test, It always writes twice to G-sheet.
Any advice will be appreciated.

1.[use web apps URL to test](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz6jaGuXmk_dnCJmJe57Vi27fZ76ZVPCd7ekbDY7M09Ob-N1V2o/exec?action_type=register&chk_mail=294pro@gmail.com&mem_pwd=3333)

2. [G-sheet URL](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1boJkgfSlQ9HPrs88gH2cPD7_Yk1EDxKpiJgtKsKNtQw/edit#gid=0)

3 [image: Script for this issue]

4.[image: switch case description]

Comment: Please paste code as text and format it using markdown. Code as image is frowned upon here :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code for the above issue. Sorry to ask a question for the first time and not to know how to post the code in question.

```js
function member_register(params)  {
   var id="1boJkgfSlQ9HPrs88gH2cPD7_Yk1EDxKpiJgtKsKNtQw";  
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("mdata"); 

  
    var currentTime = new Date();              
                                     
    sheet.appendRow([currentTime, params.mem_name, params.mem_fname,params.chk_mail,params.mem_pwd,params.mem_mobile,params.mem_addr])   
  
  var reg_result ="member register success"
   Logger.log(reg_result); 
    return reg_result
    
 
                                       }
```